# Why does my class implement child interfaces, but not their parents?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface

I found a (at least for me) unexpected behavior when using interface inheritance in Delphi.

I have this simple class and interface hierarchy:

```
+---------------+
| << IMyBase >> |
+---------------+
        ^
        |
+---------------+
| << IMyIntf >> |
+---------------+
        ^
        |
   +---------+
   | TMyObj  |
   +---------+
```

I wanted to declare a variable of type `IMyBase`. Create a `TMyObj` and assign it to my variable. IHMO this is normal OOP practice. But it turned out that it does not compile.

I Have also tried to declare a variable of type `IMyIntf` and check if it supports `IMyBase`, IMHO it should support it, but it doesn't.

Here is a simple test code:

```
program interface_inheritance;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  IMyBase = interface
    ['{CC7C61B8-3FBA-481F-AF0D-A93C603B5202}']
    procedure Hello;
  end;

  IMyIntf = interface(IMyBase)
    ['{01CE01D9-A753-431C-A30E-64BAEC6C4E26}']
    //
  end;

  TMyObj = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf)
    procedure Hello;
  end;

{ TMyObj }

procedure TMyObj.Hello;
begin
  Writeln('Hello World');
end;

var
  b: IMyBase;
  i: IMyIntf;
begin
(*  // Compile Error E2010
  b := TMyObj.Create;
  b.Hello;*)

  // Does not work as Expected
  // Does not call Hello()
  i := TMyObj.Create;
  if Supports(i, IMyBase, b) then begin
    // Why does i not support IMyBase ??
    b.Hello;
  end;

  // Works but unsafe!
  // Hard cast, without check.
  i := TMyObj.Create;
  b := IMyBase(i);
  b.Hello;

  // Works, of course!
  i := TMyObj.Create;
  i.Hello;

  Readln;
end.
```

As you can see i have a valid class/interface structure. but some parts do not compile. and some do not execute as expected.

1. Why does `b := TMyObj.Create;` give an incompatible type error?
2. Why does `Supports(i, IMyBase, b)` returns `false`?
3. Is there another (better) way to solve such a problem? without a hard cast without check? (`if i is IMyBase` does not work, because interfaces do not support `is` operator.)

Is this valid Pascal/Delphi behavior or a bug? IMHO `Supports()` should return `true`. and `TMyObj` should be a valid `IMyBase` (and therefor be assignable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might seem a little counter intuitive, but your class must declare that it implements the parent interface, too. Your class declaration must be like so:

```
TMyObj = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyBase, IMyIntf)
```

Danny Thorpe, a former Borland engineer, explained the rationale behind this behaviour in an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380371/505088):

> If an implementing class does not declare that it supports an
>   inherited interface, then the class will not be assignment compatible
>   with variables of the inherited interface. The code sample you posted
>   should work fine (using the IChild interface), but if you try to
>   assign from an instance of TMyClass to a variable of IParent, then
>   you'll run into trouble.
>
> The reason is because COM and ActiveX allow an implementation to
>   implement a descendent interface (your IChild) but deny the ancestor
>   of that interface (IParent). Since Delphi interfaces are intended to
>   be COM compatible, that's where this goofy artifact comes from.

Comment: And there is no such compiler directive of which Danny thought it could exist.